# Angular: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

With the below resolve i get this error:

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide
> an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

the problem is the api`findExerciseFrameworkByEntityUsingGET` return null.

```
@Injectable()
export class ExerciseFrameworkRouteResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private apiExerciseFramework: APIExerciseFramework) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let array: (Observable<any[]> | Observable<any>)[] = [];
        return this.apiExerciseFramework.findExerciseFrameworkByEntityUsingGET({ externalId: route.paramMap.get('entityId') }).pipe(
            mergeMap((exerciseFramework: models.ExerciseFrameworkResponse) => {
                if (exerciseFramework) {
                    array.splice(0, 0, of(exerciseFramework));
                    array.splice(1, 0, this.apiRefService.findPriceZonesUsingGET());
                    array.splice(2, 0, this.apiRefService.findIndemnityAreaUsingGET());
                    return forkJoin(array);
                }
            })
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can add an 'else' condition after 'if (exerciseFramework)' to do something like 'return of(null)' so the return will still be an observable even if that service returns null. Then, the consumer can handle what to do if the output value is null.